# Find top result for each month from a table

Tags: sql

I've got aggregate table filtered to 3 things

```
Month | Days | Total
202109 | 2  | 546
202109 | 3  | 9
202109 | 14 | 92
202108 | 2  | 666
202108 | 4  | 23
```

I wanna get new table that gives Month |  Days | Total

But only returns the entry where it has the highest total for that month
So desired result would give

```
Month | Days | Total
202109 | 2 | 546
202108 | 2 | 666
```

Any idea how I could go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select Month, Days, max(Total) 
from table1
group by Month
```

if this does now work as days must be included in group by use a temp table

```
select Month, max(Total) as Total into #temp 
from table1
group by Month

select b.Month, a.Days, b.total
from table1
inner join #temp b
on a.month = b.month and a.total = b.total
```